# Delphi RTTI SetValue for Enumerations

Tags: delphi, enumeration, rtti

How do I  use RTTI to set an enumerated field's value ?

I.e.

```
type
  TCPIFileStatus= (fsUnknown, fsProcessed);
  TTest = class
    FStatus: TCPIFileStatus; 
  end;
      ...
  var
    Data: TTest;
    Ctx: TRttiContext;
    Status : TCPIFileStatus;
  begin
    Data := TTest.Create;
    Status := fsProcessed;
    Ctx.GetType(Data.ClassType).GetField('FStatus').SetValue(Data, Status);
  end;
```

I get "Invalid class typecast."
NB:I need to use RTTI because I will not always know the object type or field name at design time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you must pass a [`TValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TValue) to the [`SetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TRttiField.SetValue) method try using this code :

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils;


type
  TCPIFileStatus= (fsUnknown, fsProcessed);
  TTest = class
    FStatus: TCPIFileStatus;
  end;

  var
    Data   : TTest;
    Ctx    : TRttiContext;
    Status : TCPIFileStatus;
    v      : TValue;
begin
  try
    Data := TTest.Create;
    try
      Status := fsProcessed;
      v:= v.From(status); 
      Ctx.GetType(Data.ClassType).GetField('FStatus').SetValue(Data, v);

      // do your stuff
    finally
       Data.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked at the FromVariant and FromOrdinal and missed the From method.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution to this problem, in the case you don't know the exact enum type on your function but instead it's TypeInfo, is to use TValue's Make procedure.

```
procedure Make(AValue: NativeInt; ATypeInfo: PTypeInfo; out Result: TValue); overload; static;
```

Here is an example (From an XML config parser):
This is later used for a TRTTIField/TRTTIProperty.SetValue()

```
function EnumNameToTValue(Name: string; EnumType: PTypeInfo): TValue;
var
  V: integer;

begin
  V:= GetEnumValue(EnumType, Name);
  TValue.Make(V, EnumType, Result);
end;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use TValue.From generic method to obtain a compatible TValue value to pass to the SetValue method...

mmm... it's hard to get from words, better code:

```
type
  TCPIFileStatus= (fsUnknown, fsProcessed);
  TTest = class
    FStatus: TCPIFileStatus;
  end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: TTest;
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Status : TCPIFileStatus;
  AValue: TValue;
begin
  Data := TTest.Create;
  try
    Status := fsProcessed;
    Ctx.GetType(Data.ClassType).GetField('FStatus').SetValue(Data, TValue.From(Status));
    Assert(Data.FStatus = Status, 'Something wrong on assigning status trough RTTI!');
  finally
    Data.Free;
  end;
end;
```